# Classes without instances - more pythonic ways?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a application in which a (bigger group of) developers add commands. These commands consist of a set of functions, mostly 'handle()' to actually perform action and descriptive properties to help the parser find the correct function.
To enforce some standards for the commands we have a baseclass that all commands need to derive from.

My issue is that these are not actually used as classes, there is never a instance of any command.

```
class command(ABC):
    '''
    class all commands inherit from
    '''

    @property
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def name():
        '''
        returns the name of the command (which the parser acts on)
        '''
        pass

    @property
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def help():
        '''
        returns the help text
        '''
        pass

    @property
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def handle():
        '''
        contains the actual command handler, may return data
        '''
        pass

class commandPrint(command):
    '''
    example
    '''

    @staticmethod
    def name():
        return 'print'

    @staticmethod
    def help():
        return 'Print some string'

    @staticmethod
    def handle(inputString):
        print(inputString)
        return inputString
```

This works well, but seems a bit 'unpythonic' as in we never create an instance of these commands. Also while this does give a frame, the purpose of an abc is of no use - we never create a instance so we never see a missing abstract method.

Is there a more pythonic way to archive this type of interfacing?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I dont think the OO approach has any issue with static only classes.

Comment: Couldn't you just use dictionaries that store functions and a dictionary creator function that demands at least name, help and handle arguments?

Comment: I don't understand your question properly, but it feels like you wish to have something `perform_operation_as_per_flag(flag)`
And inside this function you have mapping of flag to call respective functions.

Try to use `argparse` function `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`

Comment: I think that what you seem to be looking for is a module, simply import the module from outer code. Get rid of this "abstract" classes, they do not make anything clearer here.

Comment: @Abhishakegupta I think argparse is pretty overkill for our solution. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: nearly every time i end up with mostly classmethod code, as opposed to either functions or instantiated classes w methods, it ends up being less and less clever as i proceed.  if the handlers have the same signatures, could you not use Strategy pattern, for example?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to explicitly prevent this classes to be instanciated (abstract), you can use this:

```
class Command():
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

You can also raise this error `NotImplementedError` in all methods of your base class instead of `pass` to be more like an interface (that needs to re-define all the methods).

Comment: This is not my intention. We inherit from command, but never create an instance of the subclass, therefore neither the error from the abstractmethod is raised, nor would your exception be.